# MVVM Light Binding Exception

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.ios, mvvm-light

I am using Version 5.3.0 of the MVVM Light Toolkit in a Xamarin.iOS application to create databinding to ViewModels in a shared library. The binding is

```
        _bindingList.Add(
            this.SetBinding(
                () => _sessionViewModel.ActiveSession.Swings.Count,
                () => _swingCountLabel.Text,
                fallbackValue: 0,
                targetNullValue: 0)
            .ConvertSourceToTarget(c => $"({c.ToString()})"));
```

The Swings is an observable collection. ActiveSession is an observable property. As long as ActiveSession is not null this works. When ActiveSession is set to null the following exception is generated:

Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.

The error occurs in an MVVM Light function name 'SetSpecialValues'. I downloaded the source and it looks like the case where the Fallback value is used is not using the converter before calling SetValue.

The following similar binding works fine (source and destination type are the same). When ActiveSession is null it properly shows "-----".

```
        _bindingList.Add(
            this.SetBinding(
                () => _sessionViewModel.ActiveSession.Name,
                () => _sessionLabel.Text,
                fallbackValue: "-----",
                targetNullValue: "-----"));
```

Is this type of binding supported or am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: I downloaded the source and made the change in SetSpecialValues(...) and it seems to fix the issue.